# Why did the narrator of The Picture in the House need shelter?

Tags: h-p-lovecraft

H.P. Lovecraft's *The Picture in the House* begins with the narrator travelling down an abandoned road. From *"I did not hesitate to wheel my machine ..."*, I gather that he was driving a car. His journey is interrupted by *"a rain of such chilling copiousness that any shelter was preferable to exposure"*.

Why would he need to seek shelter from the rain if he was already in a car?

Comment: @Mark: Thanks for the tag. Could you change it to _the_-picture-in-the-house?

Comment: let me think about that, for some reason I think your supposed to drop the 'the' when making tags.  But I could be wrong, anyone feel free to correct me.  Similar to the reasoning that indexes often put common prepositions and 'the' at the end of a title.  I'm a huge Lovecraft fan BTW.

Comment: Looking at the [create tag page](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/privileges/create-tags), I can't find any information on the tag customs so I'll go with whatever anyone with tag privileges wants to do.

Comment: @Mark, I suppose it will solve itself through the democratic process of synonyms if there is a need.

Comment: One of the other moderators @Gilles, thought it was fine, so I changed it as you suggested.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like my premise was wrong. From a couple of paragraphs later:

> I entered, carrying my bicycle, and closed the door behind me.